# How to Create Report(Crystal) Report From Three Tables that are linked through Relationship

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have three tables linked to each other. Now I have to create a Report from them, in which i want patient Table (`ptTbl`) data only once (like patient name,address etc) but i want to show all data of these two columns `visitTbl.MedDescrp` and `visitTestTbl.visitTestDescr` on report. Like :

```
-------------------Required Report Format-------------                           
Patient Name:    ABC                
Phone:           123456              
Address:         London

(above mentioned column names are from ptTbl)        
MedDescrp:       Panadol           
                 Amoxil             
                 Calpol   etc (may be more fields)           
visitTestDescr:  Widal test          
                 sugar test               
                 ABC Test   etc (may be more fields)
```

**This is the Image of My 3 Tables :**

[image]

1. `ptTbl` is a Patient Table
2. `visitTble` is a `visitMedicine` Table
3. `visitTestTbl` is a `visitTestTable`

Any Help Would be appreciated.

Comment: is problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how many tables/fields you want to show on your report. I would suggest you to make a stored procedure, get all the fields either from one table or more, then go to report, right click on Database Fields and export your stored procedure from database, put all your stored procedure fields on your report that's it.